# Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in mssql when columns are string data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to know whether 'pivot' in MS SQL can be used for converting rows to columns if there is no aggregate function to be used. i saw lot of examples with aggregate function only. my fields are string data type and i need to convert this row data to column data.This is why i wrote this question.i just did it with 'case'. Can anyone help me......Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always use min() or max() on varchar. There should only be one value per location in pivot grid.

Comment: thanks for the response..

see my problem is, say there is one employee and he has lot data in row wise. i need to select this data as a single row. so the problem is i cant use min() or max()....

Comment: Probably best if you supply example data and some desired results for that data so we can see what you are trying to do and why `MIN` / `MAX` won't work for you.

Comment: ok.i will give u the data format.

empid  wagecode    amount
1       basic       1000
1          TA       500
1          DA       500
2          Basic    1500
2           TA      750
2           DA      750



and i need the ans as

empid    BASic      TA     DA
1         1000       500   500
2         1500       750   750

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to perform this operation. When doing the PIVOT you can do it one of two ways, with a Static Pivot that you will code the rows to transform or a Dynamic Pivot which will create the list of columns at run-time:

Static Pivot (see [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88cd4/2)):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select empid, wagecode, amount
  from t1
) x
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for wagecode in ([basic], [TA], [DA])
) p
```

Dynamic Pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(wagecode) 
                  FROM t1 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT empid, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                 select empid, wagecode, amount
                 from t1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(amount)
                for wagecode in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both of these will give you the same results

Comment: BTW - you can see you dynamic query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88cd4/4  (I just had to adjust the query terminator so the declare segment wasn't executed separately from the rest of your code)

Comment: @JakeFeasel thanks for adding that, I didn't have time to do both fiddles this morning

Comment: @bluefeet sure, no prob.  The query terminator UI control is pretty new, wasn't sure if you knew about it / when it might be useful.

Comment: @JakeFeasel its very helpful, I wasn't aware that was added.

Answer (score 1):

sample format

empid      wagecode      amount
1                      basic                     1000
1                     TA                               500
1                      DA                              500
2                      Basic                      1500
2                      TA                               750
2                     DA                               750

empid      basic       TA         DA 
1                   1000          500      500 
2                1500            750         750

THE ANSWER I GOT IS

> ```
>    SELECT empID , [1bas] as basic, [1tasal] as TA,[1otsal] as DA
>    FROM (
>    SELECT empID, wage, amount
>    FROM table) up
>    PIVOT (SUM(amt) FOR wgcod IN ([1bas], [1tasal],[1otsal])) AS pvt
>    ORDER BY empID 
>    GO
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT empid AS EmpID     
, ISNULL(SUM(CASE wagecode WHEN 'basic' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS Basic         
, ISNULL(SUM(CASE wagecode WHEN 'ta' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS TA     
, ISNULL(SUM(CASE wagecode WHEN 'da' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DA 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY empid
```

Comment: @ V.P Verma :thanks for your replay.

why i go for pivote is to reduce the complexity of the query and to reduce the execution time..i don't know exactly but i think pivote is better than case in this case..once again thanks for the replay..and want to know pivote or case is faster..